# The values of a 2D matrix is not assigning right

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm a newbie to programming and I'm trying to code to obtain the following pattern

If `n=3`

```
3 3 3
3 1 3
3 2 3
3 3 3
```

If `n=4`

```
4 4 4 4 4
4 4 1 4 4
4 4 2 4 4
4 4 3 4 4
4 4 4 4 4
```

And if `n=5`

```
5 5 5 5 5
5 5 1 5 5
5 5 2 5 5
5 5 3 5 5
5 5 4 5 5
5 5 5 5 5
```

and so on.

My code for the above pattern is below

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {

  int n, row, col, mid, i, j, mat[50][50], midValue = 1;
  printf("Enter the value of N\n");
  scanf("%d",&n );
  if(n % 2 == 0) {

    row = col = n + 1;

  }
  else{

    col = n;
    row = n + 1;

  }
  mid = col / 2;
  printf("%d\n",mid );
  for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {

    for(j = 0; j < col; j++) {

      if(j == mid && i != 0) {

          mat[row][col] = midValue;
          midValue++;

      }
      else {

        mat[row][col] = n;

      }

    }

  }

  for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {

    for(j = 0; j < col; j++) {

      printf("%d\t",mat[row][col]);

    }
    printf("\n");

  }
  return 0;

}
```

But, all my matrix elements are just set to the value of N. I couldn't figure where I've gone wrong. Can anyone point out the mistake?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Is that first pattern a type?

Comment: Without checking the rest, you certainly don't want mat[row][col] but mat[i][j] instead (3 locations).

Comment: Maybe `printf("%d\t",mat[row][col]);` should be `printf("%d\t", mat[i][j]);` — and also when you assign, as @oliver says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting and printing the only element of the matrix - `mat[row][col]`.

Neither `i` nor `j` is being used to set the values and print the values.

You need to change:

```
        mat[row][col] = midValue;
```

to

```
        mat[i][j] = midValue;
```

and

```
        mat[row][col] = n;
```

to

```
        mat[i][j] = n;
```

and

```
     printf("%d\t",mat[row][col]);
```

to

```
     printf("%d\t",mat[i][j]);
```

Comment: Omg, i feel so stupid. TY for being patient and pointing out.

Comment: @ReshmaSuresh, you are welcome. Don't feel bad. Most of us have been there at one time or another.